# Wordpress Custom Field to Delete Post after a specified date?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I Have a Freelancering website that users can send projects and find freelanceers .

I want a custom field in the Send Project Section that user can set the expire time , and when he/she sent the project , the project will be delete .

How Can I do That ? Any Suggestions will be usefull .

and If you write the codes i am very thanksfull .

Comment: Hi, @Moji.Michael for this things you have to set cron job. so everyday cron job runs automatically and check delete post date from database if any date found then set delete query for that post.

Comment: I was thinking about the [Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API), but I'm not sure if this is applicable for this use case.

Comment: @HardikKarangia is there any plugin to install and do cron jobs ? is advanced custom field plugin usefull ?

Comment: Please Refer this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46561686/wordpress-delete-posts-by-using-the-date-of-a-custom-field